# Override default nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, centos

In CentOS I installed nginx version 1.6.3 and it came with a default config file that defines a server for port 80. I put my config file in `conf.d/` but I couldn't find a way to override the default config other than modifying `nginx.conf`.

Is there a way to override or disable the default server on port 80 without modifying `nginx.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to define another main config file without modify the original nginx.conf.

```
/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/custom.conf
```

Comment: This would be practically the same as modifying the original config. But thanks, I do this, actually. It just hardly makes sense to me that the default config contains any site setup at all.

Comment: Yes it could be confusing. Apache Httpd has also a default virtualhost with the message "It works!".